# Returning values through a sub - program

Tags: c, recursion

Bellow is a simple code, which the user gives a number and it finds the fibonacci sequence until that number. The question is, if we give for example 5.
At first it runs until it reaches the `Nth_Fib_number = Fib_n(i)`.
Then it gets inside the sub program and because the i=0;(from the loop of the main program) then `res=0;` and it returns `res;` which is 0.
Second we get `i=1`;(from the loop of the main program) then `res=1`; and it returns res; which is 1.

The part that confuses me, is now for `i=2;` It goes through sub-program and navigates to `res=Fib_n(n-1)+Fib_n(n-2)`. Here res=1+0 I guess. 
After that it goes to `res=1;` and then it returns `res;` 
Again after that it goes to `res=0;` and it returns `res;` 
After that it return `res;` one more time, and goes to main.

The problem is that I can't understand what happens in the third loop. We get `res=Fib_n(2-1)+Fib_n(2-2);` and after that it calls itself again and says that `res=1;`. Why res got equal to one? Also when it returns res right after, is it returning the res with the value of 3?

I tried to debug it but I didn't manage to see the variables that I want to.

Sorry for the long post. Thanks for your time, appreciate your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Fib_n( int n);
int main( void )
{ 
    int Nth_Fib_number, i, n;
    printf("Give a number N, in order to get the Fib(N):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        Nth_Fib_number = Fib_n( i );
        printf("%d: Fibonacci( %d ) = %d\n", i, i, Nth_Fib_number);
    }
}

int Fib_n( int n)
{
    int res;

    if (n==0){
        printf("%d",res);
        res = 0;
    }else
        if (n==1)
            res = 1;
        else
            res = Fib_n(n-1) + Fib_n(n-2);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to insert some `printf()` so see what's going on? It will help you a lot. -- Oh, and please remove "C#" from your title. It's C what you're programming here, and the tag is shown anyway.

Comment: @thebusybee thanks for your reply. Sorry about the C# my bad, yeah I have tried some printf statements but still. For example I wanted to print the value of res and it shows something like 32767 which is something else, I guess.

Comment: Well, if it prints 32767 then `res` has this value. Add some more `printf()` in other branches, and don't forget to use curly braces.

Comment: @thebusybee thanks for your help! Are you talking about curly braces like {res} this or just curly braces after statements ?

Comment: When you say "subprogram" you actually mean "function", con't you? The functions in your code snippet are part of 1 single program.

Comment: See below, klutt's answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry my bad, yes I mean function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you print the value before the variable is initialized. That is undefined behavior. Remember that each time you call `Fib_n` it has a new `res` variable that is completely unrelated to previous calls.

Also, your code looks very messy. You really should put curly braces around the else block like this:

```
}else {
    if (n==1)
        res = 1;
    else
        res = Fib_n(n-1) + Fib_n(n-2);
}
```

But IMO, the code looks pretty messy anyway. I would write it like this:

```
int Fib_n(int n)
{
    if(n==0) return 0;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    return Fib_n(n-1) + Fib_n(n-2);
}
```

No need for a separate return variable for a function as simple as this.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. My problem is that i still can't understand when i=2; then it goes to return Fib_n(n-1) + Fib_n(n-2); then jumps to this if(n==1) return 1; and then when it is ready to leave the function it goes to if(n==0) return 0; again. After that it does return one more time and goes to main.

Comment: If you call Fib_n(2), then n is 2. Then this function calls Fib_n(n-1) which is Fib_n(1). What to you expect it to do?